# Create a overriden method in base class when you don't know the arguments passed to the overriding functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have an abstract class **A** which is base for the other classes, let's say **B** and **C**.

Classes **B** and **C** should have a `void` type `handle_input` method, but argument number and types may vary from **B** to **C**.

I also have a function that takes a *pointer* to an **A** as an argument - polymorphically speaking, that could be either **A**, **B** or **C** - and calls the method `handle_input`.

---

The problem comes when defining `A::handle_input` because the arguments passed to `B::handle_input` may be different to the ones passed to `C::handle_input`.

That leds me to create in class **A** something like:

```
/* base class */
class A {
    template <class... FUNCTION_ARGS>
    virtual void handle_input(FUNCTION_ARGS&&...) = 0;
};
```

But errors occur because the *template* is calculated at compile time, while *virtual* is used at run time.

I also did

```
class A {
    template <class... FUNCTION_ARGS>
    using input_handler = function<void(FUNCTION_ARGS&&...)>;

    template <class... FUNCTION_ARGS>
    input_handler<FUNCTION_ARGS...> handle_input;
};
```

But the outcome is more or less the same, as expected.

---

I guess my question would be *"How can you create a overriden method in base class when you don't know the arguments passed to the potentially multiple overriding functions?"*

Notes(correct me if I'm wrong):

- `handle_input` is dynamically polymorphic, so it has to be virtual.
- `handle_input`'s  argument number in unknown, so parameter packs must be used.

Comment: A) you cannot have a virtual template functions. B) the types in the signature of a virtual function must be the same or covariants and there must be the same number of them.

Comment: I suppose you could make an input base class then group the inputs to B and the inputs to C into 2 different classes that derive from that base input class. That way class A's virtual function could declare that it takes a pointer to the base input type. Then you'd have to do a dynamic cast inside B and C to obtain the appropriate input class which would probably have different getter functions that aren't declared in the base input class (given that it isn't common between the two input types)... not saying it's clean, but if you have to have it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've provided a vastly superior implementation with an explanation here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140510/88422

---

To circumvent what NathanOliver is saying, you can use closures. They will store their arguments, and you can call them polymorphically.

Disclaimer: This is a very barebones implementation to show the technique.

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto make_closure( F&& f, Args&&... args ) noexcept
{
    return [=] { return f( args... ); };
}

struct fn_base
{
    virtual ~fn_base() = default;
    virtual void invoke() = 0;
};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct fn : public fn_base
{
    using closure_t = decltype( make_closure( std::declval<T>(), std::declval<Args>()... ) );
    closure_t closure_;

    fn( closure_t&& closure ) : closure_{ std::move( closure ) } {}

    void invoke() override
    {
        closure_();
    }
};

template<class F, class... Args>
auto make_fn( F&& f, Args&&... args )
{
    return fn<F, Args...>{ make_closure( std::forward<F>( f ), std::forward<Args>( args )... ) };
}
```

Sample usage:

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int, char )
{
    std::cout << "f( int, char )\n";
}

void g( double )
{
    std::cout << "g( double )\n";
}

int main( int, char*[] )
{
    auto df0 = make_fn( &f, 1, 'c' );
    auto df1 = make_fn( &g, 0.5 );
    fn_base* f0 = &df0;
    fn_base* f1 = &df1;
    f0->invoke();
    f1->invoke();
}
```

Comment: I really like the concept of the solution. Seems like there is a decent amount of boiler-plate, is there a way to do the same thing just by passing argument-less lamda's with the values embedded in them?

Comment: @RyanP Could you show me (with code) what you would like to be able to write?

Comment: Isn't `return [=] { return f( args... ); };` same as `return f( args... );` in that context? What am I missing there?

Comment: @Garmekain No, because the `[=] { ... };` part is what creates the lambda closure. Otherwise, you are simply returning the result of invoking `f( args... )`. Currently, the return is a callable with no parameters.

Comment: @user2296177 My question is, what is the added benefit of using all of the template functions over something like accepting a std::function as a parameter with less boiler-plate? something like https://ideone.com/YCiBkk

Comment: Oh, that's right, little mistake there. I thought that the lambda function gets executed, but for that the lambda needs the arguments passed to it inside `()` after the function body.

Comment: @RyanP You could definitely use `std::function<>` to achieve something similar. However, there are some considerations to take: `std::function<>` will use dynamic allocation if the closure's size is larger than the statically allocated block (this is similar to the small string optimization). Using a lambda avoids this, at the cost of boilerplate and a possible code size increase.

Comment: @RyanP TL;DR: `std::function<>` will use dynamic allocation which is definitely a performance loss over my approach: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af143d1f31c8e6e5.